# delete an attribute from a JPA entity

Tags: jpa

I want to remove an attribute from my JPA entity and I want to know how to do it?

I delete it from the entity and after I generate the database or I have to delete it

from both database and entity.

thank you in advance

Comment: That has nothing to do with JSF. And do whatever you want, as long as at the end, the database schema matches with your entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choices , you can delete it from your database and then regenerate your persistence unit ( delete the old one ), that will create the entities that you will choose.

Or you can delete the attribut from your entity and you should update your persistence.xml file :

> Table generation strategy = drop and create

and then execute your project that contain the JPA persistence unit .Dont forget that you should update Table generation strategy of your persistence.xml to the value `create` again .